# RSpec hates Rails scope named :public when stubbing object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

Is it just me or is it a global RSpec behavior that when I name my rails model scope `:public`, initialize object from this model, and stub this object  Rspec fails

```
class DocumentName < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :public,    lambda{where( public: true) }  #line 3
end
```

nothing special, Rails application works

```
DocumentName.public  # => [ #DN, #DN, #DN... ]
# SELECT `document_names`.* FROM `document_names` WHERE `document_names`.`public` = 1
```

however RSpec fails

```
describe DocumentName do
  let(:resource){DocumentName.new}  
  it do
     resource.stub(:name).and_return('foo')   #line 16
     resource.save.should be true
  end
end

 Failure/Error: resource.stub(:name).and_return('foo')
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
 # ./app/models/document_name.rb:3:in `block in <class:DocumentName>'
 # ./spec/models/document_name_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

...and funniest thing, I'm not doing anything with that scope in this scenario.

However if I name this scope something else than `:public` e.g: `:are_public`:

```
class DocumentName < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :are_public,    lambda{where( public: true) }
end
```

...everything pass  O_O

```
Rails 3.2.11 (but same thing on any 3.2.x)
Ruby ruby-2.0.0-rc1 ( but same for any ruby-1.9.3) 
rspec-core (2.12.2)
rspec-expectations (2.12.1)
rspec-mocks (2.12.1)
rspec-rails (2.12.2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`private` and `public` are Ruby's access modifiers:

```
class User
  private
  def some_private_method
  end

  public
  def some_public_method
  end
end
```

While they may seem like keywords, they are actually method calls. It's not really a good idea to overwrite them.

Comment: This is probably true, but since "public" is not an Ruby reserved word, shouldn't this be considered an RSpec bug?

Comment: `public` and `private` are actual methods that are called, not some reseverd words. See my edit.